# How can I make many new web workers without loading the scripts multiple times?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a webpage that needs to do some intense calculations, so I create a web worker to help out.

The web worker is terminated after its task finishes, but I need to do the task multiple times. Is there any way I can have the webpage or browser load the worker's script files only once, then distribute them to the new workers without having to fetch them from the server again?

I could make the tasks work on only one web worker though that would be less ideal.

Comment: I have the exact same question. I'm using webpack 5.

Comment: +1. Multiple tasks in one worker doesn't help if you want multiple worker threads to run in parallel. Loading the workers from a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) avoids the repeated network request, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: @Karl It's also unclear what kind of overhead there is for having multiple instances of a web worker from the same data URL... does it share the code among the instance, for example?